# my image is displaying as a box not a hexagon

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make these hexagons in a grid-like pattern, but they are not sized properly and dont pack as tightly as I would like because they are box sprites. I checked the PNG in my file explorer and it does not have any background, it is just the hexagons.

[image: hexagons]

```js
document.getElementById("Button1").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  createCanvas();
}

function drawHexagon(x, y, scale) {
  const c = document.getElementById("hexagonCanvas");
  const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  const img = document.getElementById("whex");
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 4 * scale / Math.sqrt(3), scale);
}

function createCanvas() {
  let n = 100;
  let hex = new Array(n);
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    hex[i] = new Array(n);
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      hex[i][j] = false;
      let scale = 100;
      let y = 2 * scale * i + scale;
      let x = 2 * scale * Math.sqrt(3) * j;
      if (j % 2 == 1) {
        y += scale;
      }
      //console.log(x + " " + y + " " + i + " " + j);
      drawHexagon(x, y, scale);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/139198/isolated/lists/89ce93222bff9f1e4f6195d164d0c8bf-hexagon-shape-stroke-icon.png" id="whex" class="hola">
<canvas id="hexagonCanvas" width="2000" height="2000" style="border:1px solid grey;"></canvas>
<button id="Button1">Try it</button>
<script src="hexGame.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. I had to add a `</p>`  but it gives an error you need to solve to have a [mcve] - you can get images at https://placehold.co/ or google images

Comment: or upload to imgur

Comment: thanks for pointing out the </p> thing, however other than that I still dont understand. I'm pretty sure this was a minimal reproducible example, and I dont have any problem with images. My image is properly cropped to be a hexagon, that was what I was asking, how do I make the border of the image be a hexagon rather than a box when it appears.

Comment: But it wasn't a [mcve]. And as you can see, I misunderstood how your original image looked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `clip-path: polygon(...)` property to create a hexagon.
The border part is tricky, but doable. I wrote another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77927919/3807365) similar to this.

```css
:root {
  --cut-corner-width: 200px;
  --cut-corner-height: calc(var(--cut-corner-width) * sqrt(3) / 2);
  --cut-corner-border: 2px;
  background: white;
}

.my-polygon {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0;
}

.border-container {
  width: var(--cut-corner-width);
  height: var(--cut-corner-height);
  line-height: var(--cut-corner-height);
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.cut-corner {
  outline: none;
  width: calc(var(--cut-corner-width) - var(--cut-corner-border) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--cut-corner-height) - var(--cut-corner-border) * 2);
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--cut-corner-border);
  top: var(--cut-corner-border);
  z-index: -1;
}

.cut-corner {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-container my-polygon">
  <div class="cut-corner my-polygon">
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/200">
  </div>
</div>
```