# How to make nested square corners?

Tags: css

[image]

Hello guys, I wonder is it possible to make this kinda borders with CSS? without using a fixed image. If someone knows how to do it, please let me know.

I'd like to use this style for small and big blocks, so I want to be done in CSS.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: you could try it with clip-path https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clip-path: polygon (x y, x y, ...)` with units of `%` or `px`, so along with variables for easy width and height changes, I've just wrote this code, based on another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77927919/3807365) by me.

UPDATE: now it's even responsive to image size! Explanation: the border is just a div styled positionally having `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` slightly larger than image size. This needs a `relative` container, but why not. Other than that, the class `my-polygon` defines the shape using `%` so no problem there.

```css
:root {
  --cut-corner-size: 10px;
  --cut-corner-border: 5px;
}


.my-polygon {
  clip-path: polygon(
    calc(var(--cut-corner-size) * 2) 0,
    calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 2) 0,
    calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 2) calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size)),
    calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 1) calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size)),
    calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 1) calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 2),
    calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 0) calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 2),

    calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 0) calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 2),
    calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 1) calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 2),
    calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 1) calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 1),
    calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 2) calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 1),
    calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 2) calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 0),
    calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 2) calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 0),

    calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 2) calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 0),
    calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 2) calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 1),
    calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 1) calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 1),
    calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 1) calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 2),
    calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 0) calc(100% - var(--cut-corner-size) * 2),

    calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 0) calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 2),
    calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 1) calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 2),
    calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 1) calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 1),
    calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 2) calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 1),
    calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 2) calc(0% + var(--cut-corner-size) * 0)
  );
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


.relative-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.border-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(-1 * var(--cut-corner-border));
  top: calc(-1 * var(--cut-corner-border));
  bottom: calc(-1 * var(--cut-corner-border));
  right: calc(-1 * var(--cut-corner-border));
  background-color: green;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative-container">

  <div class="border-container my-polygon">
  </div>

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" class="my-polygon">

</div>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<div class="relative-container">

  <div class="border-container my-polygon">
  </div>

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" class="my-polygon">

</div>
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks man. This is very helpful. I just wanna ask for a little more help. Is there anyway to make it responsive? (I don't wanna specifiy width and height)